# How do i translate text in python?

Tags: python, language-translation

How do i translate text in python?

If i have text in a .int file and i would like to translate parts "Aye Aye, Captain!" and "Finish Black Peter case." to Finnish and replace them to a new file how would i do it with the same format?

```
[finishbp Data_FDK_Achievement]
LocName="Aye Aye, Captain!"
LocDescription="Finish Black Peter case."
```

The finished product should look like this

```
[finishbp Data_FDK_Achievement]
LocName="Aye Aye, kapteeni!"
LocDescription="Viimeistele Black Peter-tapaus."
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: You can try using `translate` module that uses Google translate as backend and should support Finnish. Come back and once you've tried using it in your code and you have a specific issue you need a hand with.

Answer (score 0):

With the googletrans (pypi.org/project/googletrans) module that is possible. The following code takes an input folder with text files of the format you provided (multiple occurrences are allowed), translates the relevant parts and creates a new translated text file in the output folder for every input file. 
Please be aware that google translate is not known for its accuracy. 
googletrans translated your examples:
"Finish Black Peter case." to "Valmis Musta Pekka tapaus."
"Aye Aye, Captain!" to "Ai-ai, kapteeni!"

```
from googletrans import Translator
import os
import re

INPUT_FOLDER_PATH = 'path/to/inputFolder'
OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH = 'path/to/outputFolder'

# a translator object from the googletrans api
tl = Translator()

# go through all the files in the input folder
for filename in os.listdir(INPUT_FOLDER_PATH):

    # open the file to translate and split the data into lines
    in_file = open(f'{INPUT_FOLDER_PATH}/{filename}', 'r')
    data = in_file.read()
    data = data.split('\n')

    # the modified data string we will now fill
    transl_data = ""

    # translate the relevant parts of each line
    for line in data:

        # find matches: is this a relevant line?
        locname = re.findall('(?<=LocName=").*(?=")', line)
        locdesc = re.findall('(?<=LocDescription=").*(?=")', line)

        # if there is a locName or locDescription match, translate the important part and replace it
        if len(locname) == 1:
            locname_trans = tl.translate(locname[0], dest='fi').text
            line = re.sub('(?<=LocName=").*(?=")', locname_trans, line)
        elif len(locdesc) == 1:
            locdesc_trans = tl.translate(locdesc[0], dest='fi').text
            line = re.sub('(?<=LocDescription=").*(?=")', locdesc_trans, line)

        # add the translated line to the translated string
        transl_data += line + '\n'

    # create a new file for the translations 
    out_file = open(f'{OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH}/{filename}-translated', 'w')

    # write the translated data to the output file
    out_file.write(transl_data)

    # clean up
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
```

Comment: It only gets the first part of the text. My text file has multiple parts that look like this.
```
[White Data_FDK_Achievement]
LocName="Suicide is Not an Option!"
LocDescription="Prevent Miss White from suicide."

[tobyclick Data_FDK_Achievement]
LocName="Dog-fancier"
LocDescription="Interact with Toby in every case."

[thieves Data_FDK_Achievement]
...
```

Using your code it only produces the first part into the new file 
```
[White Data_FDK_Achievement]
LocName="Itsemurha ei ole vaihtoehto!"
LocDescription="Estä Miss White itsemurhan."
```

Comment: I updated the code to translate every part of the text that should be translated